# Email HTML Blast - table with images not lining up in row?

Tags: html, email, html-table, html-email

This is my snippet of code:

```
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="580" class="email-container">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="https://www.facebook.com/classicstagecompany"><img src="http://classicstage.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Social-Facebook.jpg" width="194" height="50" alt="Follow us on Facebook!" style="display:block"/></a></td>  
            <td><a href="https://twitter.com/classicstage"><img src="http://classicstage.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Social-Twitter.jpg" width="194" height="50" alt="Follow us on Twittter!" style="display:block"/></a></td>   
            <td><a href="https://www.instagram.com/classicstage/"><img src="http://classicstage.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Social-Insta.jpg" width="194" height="50" alt="Follow us on Instagram!" style="display:block"/></a></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="http://www.classicstage.org"><img src="http://classicstage.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/footer.jpg" width="580" height="175" alt="@ClassicStage #CSCCarmenJones, www.classicstage.com, 136 E 13th St New York NY 10003"  style="display:block"/></a>
            </td>   
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Why does it look like this in Dreamweaver:

[image]

But like this in Gmail:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In a table every table should have the same number of rows or colspan can be used to span a table across multiple columns. It is not recommended to use colspan as different email clients start having hicups.

**Table inside a table column**

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="580" class="email-container">
        <tr>
            <td>
   
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="580" class="email-container">
     <tr>
      <td><a href="https://www.facebook.com/classicstagecompany"><img src="http://classicstage.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Social-Facebook.jpg" width="194" height="50" alt="Follow us on Facebook!" style="display:block"/></a></td>  
      <td><a href="https://twitter.com/classicstage"><img src="http://classicstage.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Social-Twitter.jpg" width="194" height="50" alt="Follow us on Twittter!" style="display:block"/></a></td>   
      <td><a href="https://www.instagram.com/classicstage/"><img src="http://classicstage.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Social-Insta.jpg" width="194" height="50" alt="Follow us on Instagram!" style="display:block"/></a></td> 
     </tr>
    </table>
   
   </td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="http://www.classicstage.org"><img src="http://classicstage.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/footer.jpg" width="580" height="175" alt="@ClassicStage #CSCCarmenJones, www.classicstage.com, 136 E 13th St New York NY 10003"  style="display:block"/></a>
            </td>   
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**The colspan method (for you to understand how it works)**

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="580" class="email-container">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="https://www.facebook.com/classicstagecompany"><img src="http://classicstage.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Social-Facebook.jpg" width="194" height="50" alt="Follow us on Facebook!" style="display:block"/></a></td>  
            <td><a href="https://twitter.com/classicstage"><img src="http://classicstage.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Social-Twitter.jpg" width="194" height="50" alt="Follow us on Twittter!" style="display:block"/></a></td>   
            <td><a href="https://www.instagram.com/classicstage/"><img src="http://classicstage.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Social-Insta.jpg" width="194" height="50" alt="Follow us on Instagram!" style="display:block"/></a></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><a href="http://www.classicstage.org"><img src="http://classicstage.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/footer.jpg" width="580" height="175" alt="@ClassicStage #CSCCarmenJones, www.classicstage.com, 136 E 13th St New York NY 10003"  style="display:block"/></a>
            </td>   
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Try the first one (it will work).

Cheers